# Accessing Javascript Class Object In Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, plugins

I have been trying to learn how to build jQuery plugins, so I'm still new at this.  Since this is my first plugin, I decided I would try a simple collapsible panel/box (you can only read so much, right?).  I'm having difficulty accessing my reference to my Javascript class object when the click event triggers.  I know that this inside of the event refers to the element that triggered the event.  I also know that I can do something like `_self = this;` before the event, but that will only cache the last object from the collection.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can keep a reference to the class object?

Thanks!

Here is my code.

HTML code

```
<div class="mypanel" title="Panel 1">Testing panel 1</div>
<div class="mypanel" title="Panel 2">Testing panel 2</div>
$('.mypanel').collapsiblePanel();
```

Plugin code

```
var contentVisible = 'showContent', contentNotVisible = 'hideContent';

;(function($) {
    var pluginName = 'collapsibleBox';

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.ele = element;
        this.$ele = $(element);
        var _self = this;

        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);

        this.init();

        /* Expose methods of Plugin we wish to be public.
         * This gets stored when the plugin is created
         */
        return {
            option: this.option,
            destroy: this.destroy
            /* Other public methods here */
        }
    }
    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        /* If the first parameter is a string, treat this as a call to a public method. */
        if(typeof arguments[0] === 'string') {
            var methodName = arguments[0];
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            var returnVal;
            this.each(function() {
                /* Check that the element has a plugin instance, and that
                 * the requrested public method exists.
                 */
                if($.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName) && typeof $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)[methodName] === 'function') {
                    /* Call the method of the Plugin instance, and Pass it the supplied arguments */
                    returnVal = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)[methodName].appy(this, args);
                }
                else {
                    $.error('Method ' + methodName + ' does not exist on jQuery.' + pluginName);
                }
            });
            if(returnVal !== undefined) {
                /* If the method returned something, return it */
                return returnVal;
            }
            else {
                /* Otherwise, returning 'this' preserves chainability */
                return this;
            }
        }
        /* If the first parameter is an object (options), or was omitted,
         * instantiate a new instance of the plugin
         */
        else if(typeof options === 'object' || !options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                /* Only allow the plugin to be instantiated once */
                if(!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                    /* Pass options to Plugin constructor, and store Plugin
                     * instance in the element's jQuery data object
                     */
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        onInit: function() {},
        onDestroy: function() {}
    };

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            this.createContentArea();
            this.createTitleBar();
            this.hook('onInit');
        },
        createContentArea: function() {
            /* ... */
        },
        createTitleBar: function() {
            /* ... */

            this.$title.click(function() {
                if(this.$ele.data('state') == contentVisible) { // The problem is here
                    this.collapse();
                }
                else {
                    this.expand();
                }
            });
        },
        expand: function() {
            this.$content.slideDown();
            this.$ele.data('state', contentVisible);
        },
        collapse: function() {
            console.log(this);
            this.$content.slideUp();
            this.$ele.data('state', contentNotVisible);
        },
        /* Use this function to get/set variables */
        option: function (key, val) {
            if(val) {
                this.options[key] = val;
            }
            else {
                return this.options[key];
            }
        },
        destroy: function () {
            /* ... */
        },

        hook: function (hookName) {
            if(this.options[hookName] !== undefined) {
                this.options[hookName].call(this.ele);
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is this an established plugin pattern?

Comment: From all of the different patters I have looked at, this was one of them.  If you have a suggestion on another pattern, I would gladly try it.

Comment: I use the pattern "best practices" pattern explained in [this jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). You need to invest some time to learn it but I reckon it's a good investment. The section at the bottom `if ( methods[method] ) {...}` is always the same leaving you free to write the methods. Something they don't explain is that you can also have private vars and private functions defined outside the methods object; this can be useful. I always define private `var pluginName = '...'` as in your pattern, to save having to write the plugin name in several places.

Comment: I have read that tutorial many times.  The only issue I have with that method, as you have stated, is that it doesn't explain private vars and functions that persist after initializing the plugin.  That is the reason I settled on the pattern I did.  Even if I had used the pattern from that tutorial, I would still have the same question I do here.  How to reference something that is not in the click function.  In the end, I hacked a solution using the `.call()` function to make sure that the function is always being called from the parent.  Not ideal, but works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue using a combination of the `.data()` method and the `.call()` method to ensure that the context of the function call is always the parent element.  I managed to get this working using the pattern I had as well as using the pattern suggested by the jQuery Plugin Authoring Tutorial.  Whether this was the correct way to do it or not, I don't know.

```
var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
        var $this = $(this), data = {};
        /* Set a local copy of the options */
        data.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        /* Create the content area */
        data.$content = createContentArea(this);
        /* Create the title bar */
        data.$title = createTitleBar(this, data.options.header, data.options.title);

        /* Show/Hide the content based on the default state passed in */
        if(data.options.defaultState == contentVisible) {
            data.$content.show();
            data.state = contentVisible;
        }
        else {
            data.$content.hide();
            data.state = contentNotVisible;
        }

        /* Add the title click event */
        data.$title.click(function() {
            methods.toggle.call($(this).parent());
        });

        /* Add the public methods */
        data.methods = {
            toggle: methods.toggle, 
            expand: methods.expand, 
            collapse: methods.collapse
        };
        return data;
    }, 
    toggle: function() {
        var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('plugin_' + pluginName);
        if(data.state == contentVisible) {
            methods.collapse.call(this);
        }
        else if(data.state == contentNotVisible) {
            methods.expand.call(this);
        }
    }, 
    expand: function() {
        var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('plugin_' + pluginName);
        data.$content.slideDown();
        data.state = contentVisible;
        $this.data('plugin_' + pluginName, data);
    }, 
    collapse: function() {
        var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('plugin_' + pluginName);
        data.$content.slideUp();
        data.state = contentNotVisible;
        $this.data('plugin_' + pluginName, data);
    }
};
```